# how do I make git stop staging files that are included in .gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore, python-venv

I'm learning git and completely lost track of what I'm doing in the process. I cloned my repo, created a folder structure and a virtual environment (which I wanted to exclude in .gitignore) and staged the whole creation.

What I did cronologically, is as follows:

1. I created a folder "python-projects" and cloned my git repo into it.
2. Then I created the folder structure in it as below:

python-projects/
...   .git
...   README.md
...   django4/
... ... projcet-blog/
... ... project-jobapp/

3. created a virtual environment named "env" in the folder project-jobapp (`python3 -m venv env` --> hence the folder "env" below)
4. started a django project named "jobapp in the folder project-jobapp (hence the folder jobapp below)
5. I created a .gitignore file in the folder project-jobapp with the content ".venv". so in the end i had the following structure:

python-projects/
...   .git
...   README.md
...   django4/
... ...      projcet-blog/
... ...      project-jobapp/
... ... ...     .gitignore
... ... ...      jobapp/
... ... ...      env/

6. in the folder project-jobapp I ran `git add *`.

What happened is that git staged the whole virtual environment as well, i see it in `git status`. However, this was exactly what I did not want it to do.

What I actually wanted to do: stage the whole folder strucutre WITHOUT the virtual environment.

So, I tried to solve it with the following steps:

1. in the folder project-jobapp I ran `git reset HEAD *` --> this cleared my staging area, thus I was at the beginning, as if I had done nothing yet...
2. I googled solutions for how to not stage, and stumbled upon `git rm --cached`, so tried it on the README.md in the parent folder... now I succesfully removed it from being tracked... but...

If i run `git add *` in the parent folder, the venv still gets staged, but README.md no more... :D

To sum it up, I find no solution for:

1. add README.md back to the tracked files
2. remove my venv from being tracked and staged
3. what would have been the correct sequence of steps, and the correct way to ignore the virtual environment, now, that you know what i wanted to achieve?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Can you clarify you have `.venv` `env` and `venv`  ?
Try to add and commit .gitignore first.

Comment: the name of the virtual einvironment is "env". It is located in the folder structure as above. What would be the correct content of .gitignore in this case? ".env"?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `env/` into the `.gitignore` file

django4/project-jobapp/.gitignore

```
env/
```

With this ignore file I did the git add * ass you say with a foo and bar files for example

```
git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
    new file:   django4/project-blog/foo
    new file:   django4/project-jobapp/.gitignore
    new file:   django4/project-jobapp/bar

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    README.md
```

With those files

```
├── django4
│   ├── project-blog
│   │   └── foo
│   └── project-jobapp
│       ├── .gitignore
│       ├── bar
│       └── env
│           ├── bin
|           [...]
│
├── .git
│   ├── branches
|   [...]
|
└── README.md
```

Comment: Thank you very much! From this I learned that .gitignore will not make the subdirectory of the subdirectory ignored. Thus, you have to put .gitignore in the subdirectory and add sub-subdirectory/. 

For the current example: if I put .gitignore with the content project-jobapp/env/ in the directory django4, git will not ignore project-jobapp/env/.

But if I put the .gitignore into project-jobapp/ with the content env/, it will ignore env. 

Thank you very much!